# Change/hide price on WooCommerce homepage with php

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm trying to change the display price on my homepage. So I've just hidden all product prices on shop page and product page, but I need help with my home page with "[best_selling_products]" section.

This is my code to hide the price on other pages, like shop and product page: (very simple but work fine)

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'ioele_hide_price_not_user_login', 10, 2 );

function ioele_hide_price_not_user_login( $price ) {

if ( (is_product_category()|| is_product() || is_shop()) && !is_user_logged_in()) {
    return '';// Empty string = no price!
}
return $price;
}
```

How can I modify this snippet to hide the price on my homepage? is_shop() hide on shop page, is_prouct() hide on product page, is_product_category() hide on product category.. and in my homepage??? I'm using WooCommerce shortcode to show my best_selling_products.

Answer (score 2):

```
if ( is_front_page() && is_home() ) {
// Default homepage

} elseif ( is_front_page()){
// Static homepage

} elseif ( is_home()){

// home page

}
```

Have you tried this.?